# Calcular numero par o impar

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber la forma de hacer mas eficiente mi código para calcular un numero par o impar. 
Como está ahora funciona, pero no se si sea la mejor manera de hacerlo (sobre todo por la penúltima linea, que la repetí para que el programa no cayera en un bucle infinito)

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un número (-1 para salir)");
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (num != -1)
            {

                if (num % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Par");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Impar");
                }
              num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
```

Comment: Si quieres ahorrarte volver ha hacer el `Console.ReadLine()` en vez de hacer un bucle `while` puedes hacer un bucle `do{...}while();`, pero de está forma tienes que poner otra sentencia `if` comprobando si es `!=-1` .

Answer (score 2):

Podrias analizar algo como esto

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un número (-1 para salir)");

while(true)
{
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if(num == -1)
        break;

    if (num % 2 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Par");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Impar");

}
```

en donde la pregunta la ubicas dentro del loop para asi entrar en un ciclo pidiendo el ingreso del valor, pero saliendo cuando evaluas el ingreso del `-1`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Una duda. Tenia entendido que usar el "break" para terminar un ciclo se considera como una mala practica dentro de la programación, ¿que tan cierto es eso?

Comment: no para nada, lo que es mala practica es salir de un ciclo usando el `goto` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto  se mantiene por compatibilidad pero no debe usarse